# Easy JsRender for loop is not working

Tags: jsrender

I am trying to render some items in a list using JsRender.
See http://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/PTWnq/1/

I am not getting any feedback from jsFiddle as to why this is not working. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the debugger says:

```
GET http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The correct address would be:

```
http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/jsrender.js
```

Then your braces are wrong:

```
$('#departmentList').html($('#DepartmentTemplate').render(data));
```

And the template has whitespace that breaks it, this is better:

```
<script id="DepartmentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
      {{for BusinessUnitName}}
            <li>{{:#data}}</li>
      {{/for}}
</script>
```

Comment: The correct address is http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/jsrender.js. If you correct that in your answer I will give you a tick because you got everything else right.

Comment: @arame3333, both are actually working addresses, but I don't mind so I edited.

Comment: The one you gave me did not work for me, something about MIME types.

Answer (score 1):

Look at you brackets, move one of them (from html to the end):

```
$('#departmentList').html($('#DepartmentTemplate').render(data));
```